# Testing for Homoscedasticity and Independence of Residuals

Tags: regression, heteroscedasticity

I ran a multiple linear regression model for a study where I try to predict different companies' emission levels using a few predictors. Two of my predictors are categorical and I performed one hot encoding on my dataset.

To check if my regression model violates the assumptions of linear regression, I plot residuals against fitted values to check for homoscedasticity, and I also plotted residuals against my y_test values to check for the independence of residuals. I ended up with the following two plots:

[image]

[image]

My y variable, emissions, is a continuous variable. I reckon that the lines are a result of one hot encoding, but I can't tell if the homoscedasticity and independent residuals assumptions have been violated. For the second plot, it seems to me that there is no relationship between y and residuals and hence the residuals are independent. I am not sure, though. Can someone help with interpreting these two plots? Thanks!

Comment: Definitely figure out why those multiple offset lines are there before worrying about other approaches to accounting for heteroschedasticity.

Comment: Emissions measurements do not look continuous at all!